# Transferring exotic domain names to major registrars

Tags: domains, domain-registrar

I am new to buying domain names and know they can be transferred from one registrar to another. Are there any limitations? Some registrars describe how to transfer domains from specific registrars, does this mean all others are not supported? Also, is there a standard as to how much the transfer costs and what the annual fees will be?

I am interested in how this works in general, but specifically I am looking into buying a .vu domain name and would like to transfer it to one of the main registrars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can transfer your domain from one domain registrar to another.

From [ICANN's Policy](http://www.icann.org/en/resources/registrars/transfers/policy-01jun12.htm) on transfer of domain between registrars

> Registered Name Holders must be able to transfer their domain name registrations between Registrars provided that the Gaining Registrar's transfer process meets the minimum standards of this policy and that such transfer is not prohibited by ICANN or Registry policies.

But a few conditions have to be met.

> ## B. ICANN-Approved Transfers
>
> (a) The gaining Registrar must be accredited by ICANN for the Registry TLD and must have in effect a Registry-Registrar Agreement with Registry Operator for the Registry TLD.
>
> (b) ICANN must certify in writing to Registry Operator that the transfer would promote the community interest, such as the interest in stability that may be threatened by the actual or imminent business failure of a Registrar.

I think `section a` is key here. You can only transfer a domain to a registrar if that registrar is accredited to hold that TLD. So if you want to transfer a `.vu` domain, then the registrar you want to transfer to should be accredited to operate the `.vu` TLD.

Some of the registrars that sell the `.vu` TLD(not an exhaustive list)

- [Gandi](https://www.gandi.net/domain/price/detail/vu/)
- [Marcaria](http://www.marcaria.com/register/domain/domain_registration.asp?country=vu&gclid=CKalz-KahrUCFZEf6wodvUYAtA)
- [101domain](http://www.101domain.com/vu.htm)
- [Innter.net](http://www.innter.net/en/domain/domains/v/vu_domain.php)
- [vuNIC](http://www.vunic.vu/newname.html?FAEFCEA1;;)

Transferring a domain is a relatively easy thing do to. Basically you need to get an Authorization code from your current registrar, and give it to the gaining registrar. Every domain registrar has(or should have) an FAQ on how to transfer your domain. [Here](http://www.quackit.com/domain-names/how_to_transfer_a_domain_name.cfm) is an overview of how it works

Answer (score 1):

This question will need to be answered within the FAQ of which ever domain company you are thinking of transfering the domain too.

Some companies allow a large range of different top level domains and country domains while some don't. The best bet is to check companies such as GoDaddy, 1and1.co.uk, 123reg etc etc - Your find this information by doing GoDaddy Transfer Information and so forth in Google Search.

Answer (score -1):

If you're planning on getting some of the general TLDs, such as .com or .net, then you won't have much of a problem when transferring registrars.

If you plan on buying more exotic domains, such as the one you want - .vu, then you might encounter a problem. ICANN requires that both registrars must be accredited to carry that specific domain extension in their list.

In terms of policies, each registrar company hs their own so you'd need to check as well. Some of them allow transfers for a fee, some are free provided that you stay with them for a few years.

Anyway, I don't understand why you plan to transfer from the start? Might I suggest a secure and safe registrar instead. Not sure about the transfer fee as it might vary per domain name.

Comment: Many ccTLDs are controlled by the country, either sold by the government itself, or by just one or a few companies on behalf of the country.